# Dropbox sync status is not visible in Xubuntu. Is this normal or only with me?

Tags: xubuntu, dropbox

As on Windows there are no icons showing *syncing* or the *green tick* showing sync is complete. All folders and files are just regular folder and files. Is this normal with Xubuntu? Though when hovering pointer to Dropbox icon it tells that syncing is going on or complete but this should also be visible on files.

Comment: I don't see that with Xubuntu (Thunar) or with Lubuntu (PCManFM). Don't know about Nautilus.

Comment: you mean the syncing status on files?

Comment: Yes, that's what I meant. In both Lubuntu and Xubuntu the only clue I know of is the animation of the icon in my panel.

Comment: Okay. Yes while changing themes or not the animation on the Dropbox happens but it should be on Files too. As with that, surely Nautilus may also be lacking this.

Answer (score 3):

Yes this is normal. Dropbox client only supports Nautilus/Files (it's default Ubuntu and Ubuntu Gnome file manager), sync status on files are only displayed on it or in some of its forks (like Nemo).

Xubuntu uses Thunar as its file manager. There is a [plugin](http://www.webupd8.org/2012/08/how-to-install-dropbox-in-xubuntu-and.html) for Thunar that will enable some basic Dropbox integration, only rigth-click menu options, not emblems.

Answer (score 0):

As a workaround, you can use caja file manager (instead of thunar) along with caja-dropbox, which precisely shows sync icons on each file within dropbox.